# is it possible to customize e.g a django app model field with html/css

Tags: python, django

[I have this model field that holds the description(image from django-admin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymdtB.png)
but when I print it out on the page it looks like the following:
[description model field printed on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tod9l.png)

so is it possible to edit the description field so it looks better and is more readable using html/css etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is understood:
You have an model field for the description and want to style the description (only this one)?

If yes:
No its not because think about it:

Example:
Anyone can create a Blog. A blog has:
-Title
-Description
-User
...

If you would now take the model field in your .html file and it would even be possible to change, that would make no sense, because every blog has a different description.

You could wrap the whole description in an html tag and style it, but not style single words...

I hope that answers your question.

Please ignore the horrible formatting, i am new to SO and typing all this on my smartphone

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Emre19 thanks for this. I suspected as much.